# PHP table display for multidimensional array error

Tags: php, html, arrays, echo

I am trying to display the output of this query:

```
  $resultReturn = $con->prepare( "SELECT `returns`.`return_id`, `returns`.`return_ZDTicket`,  status.status_description, orders.customer_email\n"

    . "FROM `returns` \n"

    . " LEFT JOIN `status` ON `returns`.`return_status` = `status`.`status_id`\n"

    . "    LEFT JOIN `agents` ON `returns`.`agent_id` = `agents`.`id`\n"

    . "    LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `returns`.`return_orderID` = `orders`.`order_id`\n"

    . "WHERE `agents`.`id` = ? ");


$resultReturn->bind_param('i', $id);
$resultReturn->execute();
$resultReturn->store_result();
$resultReturn->bind_result($returnID, $returnZD, $returnStatus,$returnCustomerEmail);


$arrayReturnID[] = array();
$arrayreturnZD[] = array();
$arrayreturnStatus[] = array();
$arrayreturnCustomerEmail[] = array();

while ($resultReturn->fetch()){
    array_push($arrayReturnID,$returnID);
    array_push($arrayreturnZD,$returnZD);
    array_push($arrayreturnStatus,$returnStatus);
    array_push($arrayreturnCustomerEmail,$returnCustomerEmail);

}

array_splice($arrayReturnID, 0, 1);
array_splice($arrayreturnZD, 0, 1);
array_splice($arrayreturnStatus, 0, 1);
array_splice($arrayreturnCustomerEmail, 0, 1);

$returnsTable = array($arrayReturnID,$arrayreturnZD,$arrayreturnStatus,$arrayreturnCustomerEmail);
```

if we print the $returnsTable this is the result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 268903 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => OPEN ) [3] => Array ( [0] => mariorossi@testnetatmo.com ) )
```

This is my table:

```
          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <th>Return ID</th>
              <th>ZD Ticket</th>
              <th>Return Status</th>
              <th>Customer Email</th>
          </tr>
              <?php  ?>
          <tr>
          </tr>
              <?php ?>
          </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
```

Can you please help me display the table? It is driving me crazy, php is not my thing! :( Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch the 4 `array_splice` calls and instead take just the first element of each array:

```
$returnsTable = array($arrayReturnID[0],$arrayreturnZD[0],$arrayreturnStatus[0],$arrayreturnCustomerEmail[0]);
```

This will make `$returnsTable` a simple array that you can loop through with a simple foreach:

```
          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <th>Return ID</th>
              <th>ZD Ticket</th>
              <th>Return Status</th>
              <th>Customer Email</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <?php 
              foreach($returnsTable as $item){
                  echo "<td>".$item."</td>";
              }
              ?>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: the problem is that when i use array_push it pushes the elements in the array in indexes 0+1 so the 0 one is always empty.

Comment: Then a simple solution would be to keep the 4 arry_splice and then make the $returnsTable array with the 0 indices as I show instead of taking the whole arrays

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, as per your question: *"I am trying to display the output of this query"*.

...and that you want the full content of the query returned (otherwise you should narrow down your query). You don't need to keep moving data with array functions just output it.

Currently your code doesn't add any `HTML` tags to show output...

```
<?

 $resultReturn = $con->prepare("
    SELECT 
        `returns`.`return_id`, `returns`.`return_ZDTicket`,
        `status`.`status_description`, `orders`.`customer_email`
    FROM `returns`
        LEFT JOIN `status` ON `returns`.`return_status` = `status`.`status_id`
        LEFT JOIN `agents` ON `returns`.`agent_id` = `agents`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `returns`.`return_orderID` = `orders`.`order_id`
    WHERE `agents`.`id` = ? ");


$resultReturn->bind_param('i', $id);
$resultReturn->execute();
$resultReturn->store_result();
$resultReturn->bind_result($returnID, $returnZD, $returnStatus,$returnCustomerEmail);

$returnTable = "";                                     // Initialise output variable
while ($resultReturn->fetch()){                        // Loop through results
    $returnTable .= "<tr>";                            // Start a new table row
    $returnTable .= "<td>{$returnID}</td>";            // Return table data in a cell
    $returnTable .= "<td>{$returnZD}</td>";            // ^^
    $returnTable .= "<td>{$returnStatus}</td>";        // ^^
    $returnTable .= "<td>{$returnCustomerEmail}</td>"; // ^^
    $returnTable .= "</tr>";                           // End table row
}

?>

          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <th>Return ID</th>
              <th>ZD Ticket</th>
              <th>Return Status</th>
              <th>Customer Email</th>
          </tr>
              <?php  echo $returnTable; ?>              // Print table content to page
          </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
```